# Iterator woes with C++ strings

Tags: c++, string, iterator

For an assignment, we have to do a large program that manipulates C++ strings in a variety of ways. Most of it is working, but this particular function is messing with me. I am trying to cycle through a string and remove all non-alphanumeric (tab, blank newline) characters before the first alphanumeric one occurs, and then end the string when the first non-alphanumeric character appears again. For example, "    bob jon" would be saved as "bob". Something is going wrong where every string is considered empty. Most peers have been telling be that

```
*(point++) = *marker;
```

can't be done and that I should change this before trying anything else...is this a way to increment the iterator while assigning its value to another iterator's value? Is it that the problem or something else?

```
void clean_entry( const string& j, string& k )
{
    string::iterator point = k.begin();
    bool checker = false;
    //cycle through the constant string and check for numbers and letters
    for(string::const_iterator marker = j.cbegin(); marker!=j.cend(); ++marker)
    {
        if( isalnum(*marker) == true )
        {
           *(point++) = *marker; //copy to the new k string if alphanum, and increment iterator
            cout << "I found a real letter!" << endl; //debugging
            checker = true;
        }
        else if( checker == true )
            break;
    }
    cout << "So far we have " << k << endl; //debugging
    if (checker == false )
        k = "(empty word)";

    cout << "The new string is " << k << " apparently." << endl; //debugging
}
```

Comment: Run in a debugger, and step through the code line by line, to see what really happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `isalnum` doesn't return `bool`. It returns `int`. The guarantee is that it returns nonzero if the character is alphanumeric and zero otherwise.This means that you can't compare the return value to `true`, as that comparison causes `true` to be converted to `int`, yielding `1`, before the comparison is done.. `if(isalnum(*marker))` is both idiomatic and actually works.

   Similarly, `if( checker == true )` is bloated and should be `if(checker)`, and `if (checker == false )` should be `if(!checker)`.
2. Your interface is questionable, since the caller must ensure that `k`'s size is large enough to accommodate the resulting string. Better to clear `k` and then use `push_back()` or similar rather than an iterator.

On the assumption that `k.size()` is sufficiently large, there's nothing wrong with `*(point++) = *marker;`.